# Gas estimation failed error:Can someone help me to resolve this error,Many thanks

Tags: blockchain, remix, metamask, pending-transactions

I'am facing this error:gas estimation failed:"gas estimation errored with a following message .the transaction execution will likely fail.do u want to force sending?gas required exceeds allowance(1882575)or always failing transaction"

**ERC20.SOL**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

/**
 * @title SafeMaths
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract ERC20 {
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] memory dests, uint256[] memory  values) public returns (uint256);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract StandardToken is ERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    /**
    * @dev transfer token for a specified address
    * @param _to The address to transfer to.
    * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
    */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to].add(_value) >= balances[_to]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
    * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
    * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
    */
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }


    /**
    * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
    * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
    * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
    * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
    */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
    *
    * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
    * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
    * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
    * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
    * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
    */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        emit Approval(msg.sender , _spender,  _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
    * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
    * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
    * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
    */
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    /**
    * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
    * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
    * the first transaction is mined)
    * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
    */
    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];

        if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
          allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
        } else {
          allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
        }

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
        return true;
    }

}

contract Anusha is StandardToken {
    string public constant name = "Anusha";
    string public constant symbol = "ecxx";
    uint256 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 88888888 * (10**decimals);
    address public tokenWallet;

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        tokenWallet = msg.sender;
        balances[tokenWallet] = totalSupply;
    }
}
```

**Ownable.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;


/*
 * Ownable
 *
 * Base contract with an owner.
 * Provides onlyOwner modifier, which prevents function from running if it is called by anyone other than the owner.
 */
contract Own {
  address public owner;
  
  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender == owner)
      _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) owner = newOwner;
  }
```

**Airdrop.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "./Ownable.sol";
import  "./ERC20.sol";


contract Airdropper is Own {

    function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] memory dests, uint256[] memory values) public
    returns (uint256) {
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (i < dests.length) {
           ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], values[i]);
           i += 1;
        }
        return(i);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess.. the transaction will revert and remix tried to warn you.. but with bad error message or it has endless loop... check the code again

Comment: Do I need to change that while loop?

Comment: @Anu The Airdropper contract tries to transfer his tokens to the destination addresses. Have you sent the tokens to Airdropper?

Comment: Sorry to asking you ,I'am new to this,can you please tell me how can i do that?